# Variable removal in docplex

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I am trying to implement Column Generation using docplex. Is there any way to remove variables that have been already added to the model?

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=52624245-1cac-442c-868a-8ec74d4914f9). The first answer given there is "Removing variables is not supported in docplex models. You can set the coeffcients to 0."